# Using a list element as color for addRectFilled

Tags: jython, jes

The following code was created in JES and uses JES built-in functions: makeEmptyPicture(),requestInteger(),addRectFilled. Otherwise the code is self contained.
It returns error "Last input is not a color".
c[n] seems to be the problem. 
Could someone please explain why?

```
barChart=makeEmptyPicture(500,500)
bars=[0]

c = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","magenta","black","gray"]

nbars=requestInteger("How many bars")
for n in range(nbars):
  bars.append(requestInteger("Enter Bar Value"))

for n in range(len(bars)):
  addRectFilled(barChart ,(30+n*30) , 500-bars[n] , 20 , bars[n] ,c[n])

show(barChart)
```

Tried a variation:

```
addRectFilled(barChart ,(30+n*30) , 500-bars[n] , 20 , bars[n] ,c[2])
```

Throws the same error

Cheers

Paul Greenwood

Comment: Can you provide a code sample that others can run?  This sample includes numerous references to functions not defined outside of the sample.

Comment: Should have mentioned, this was created in JES and uses JES built-in functions: makeEmptyPicture(),requestInteger(),addRectFilled. Otherwise the code is self contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `c[n]` is being used to choose a color from the array named `c`, but sometimes your value for `n` is too large. So, what's happening is you are using `c[n]` as input to the function

```
addRectFilled(barChart ,(30+n*30) , 500-bars[n] , 20 , bars[n] ,c[n])
```

but that last input value is going to be null if that `n` is too large. You might want to consider something like modulo so that you would cycle through the colors.

Your color values in your array are also strings rather than colors. You can make them into colors by removing the quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Even if I substitute a value for n in c[n] the issue remains:

Comment: Oh, I see now. I think my previous answer still applies, but even when n was small, your values were strings rather than colors. Try to remove the quotes around the colors and it works for me that way. I think you'll still need to address large values of n if you have more bars than colors in the array.

Comment: @PaulGreenwood To mark an answer as accepted, click the outline of a check mark under the vote down button, or answer the question yourself and mark that as an answer.  Editing an existing post to include your solution is the incorrect way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Removed quotes from colors[] list
Used modulo to cycle through colors

```
barChart = makeEmptyPicture(500,500)
bars=[]
colors = [red,orange,yellow,green,blue,magenta,black,gray]

nbars=requestInteger("How many bars")
for n in range(nbars):
  bars.append(requestInteger("Enter Bar Value " +str(n+1)))

for n in range(len(bars)):
  barColor = colors[(n)%8]
  addRectFilled(barChart ,(10+n*30) , 500-bars[n] , 20 , bars[n] ,barColor)
show(barChart)
```